# How to have QTreeWidgetItems of different heights in a QTreeWidget utilizing QStyledItemDelegate?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

**NOTE: it turned out that the problem was not due to the implementation of `QStyledItemDelegate`, but it was the fact that in the constructor of `MyTreeWidget` I was calling [setUniformRowHeights(true)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#uniformRowHeights-prop). The code below and the solution posted by @scopchanov are valid and working**

`QTreeWidget` has a protected method called `itemFromIndex()` and this is how I am making it accessible:

```
class MyTreeWidget : public QTreeWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyTreeWidget(QWidget *parent) : QTreeWidget(parent) {
        setItemDelegate(new MyItemDelegate(this));
    }

    QTreeWidgetItem treeWidgetItemFromIndex(const QModelIndex& index) {
        return itemFromIndex(index);
    }
}
```

In my `QStyledItemDelegate`, I am storing a pointer to `MyTreeWidget` and then overriding its virtual `sizeHint()` method and based on the type of the `QTreeWidgetItem` adding a padding.

```
class MyItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyItemDelegate(QObject *parent) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent) {
        _myTreeWidget = dynamic_cast<MyTreeWidget*>(parent);
    }

    QSize sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const {
        auto treeWidgetItem = _myTreeWidget->treeWidgetItemFromIndex(index);
        QSize padding;
        if (dynamic_cast<MyCustomTreeWidgetItem1*>(treeWidgetItem) {
            padding = {0, 5};
        } else if (dynamic_cast<MyCustomTreeWidgetItem2*>(treeWidgetItem) {
            padding = {0, 10};
        }

        return QStyledItemDelegate::sizeHint(option, index) + padding;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, since `sizeHint()` of the delegate doesn't get called for every single `QTreeWidgetItem`.

So my text options to call `setSizeHint()` in the constructor of `MyCustomTreeWidgetItem1`, and that didn't seem to have any effect either. Is `Qt` ignoring it because there is a delegate?

Another option was to set a minimum height of a `QWidget` that is contained in `MyCustomTreeWidgetItem` which is made possible via the `QTreeWidget::setItemWidget()`.

So it looks like the moment I use the delegate, I am confined to only size. Is my option to get rid of the delegate or there's something else I can try?

I know many people would say switch from a `QTreeWidget` to a `QTreeView`, but it's not possible at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

I would approach this problem in a different (simpler) manner:

1. Define an enumeration for the different item sizes, e.g.:

   ```
    enum ItemType : int {
        IT_ItemWithRegularPadding,
        IT_ItemWithBigPadding
    };
   ```
2. When creating an item, set the desired size in its user data, depending on its type, e.g.:

   ```
    switch (type) {
    case IT_ItemWithRegularPadding:
        item->setData(0, Qt::UserRole, QSize(0, 5));
        break;
    case IT_ItemWithBigPadding:
        item->setData(0, Qt::UserRole, QSize(0, 10));
        break;
    }
   ```
3. In the reimplementation of `sizeHint` retrieve the desired size from the index's data, e.g.:

   ```
    QSize sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                   const QModelIndex &index) const override {
        return QStyledItemDelegate::sizeHint(option, index)
                + index.data(Qt::UserRole).toSize();
    }
   ```

### Example

Here is an example I wrote for you to demonstrate how the proposed solution could be implemented:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
#include <QTreeWidget>
#include <QBoxLayout>

class Delegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    explicit Delegate(QObject *parent = nullptr) :
        QStyledItemDelegate(parent){
    }

    QSize sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                   const QModelIndex &index) const override {
        return QStyledItemDelegate::sizeHint(option, index)
                + index.data(Qt::UserRole).toSize();
    }
};

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
public:
    enum ItemType : int {
        IT_ItemWithRegularPadding,
        IT_ItemWithBigPadding
    };

    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) :
        QWidget(parent) {
        auto *l = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        auto *treeWidget = new QTreeWidget(this);
        QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> items;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            items.append(createItem(QString("item: %1").arg(i),
                                    0.5*i == i/2 ? IT_ItemWithRegularPadding
                                                 : IT_ItemWithBigPadding));

        treeWidget->setColumnCount(1);
        treeWidget->setItemDelegate(new Delegate(this));
        treeWidget->insertTopLevelItems(0, items);

        l->addWidget(treeWidget);

        resize(300, 400);
        setWindowTitle(tr("Different Sizes"));
    }

private:
    QTreeWidgetItem *createItem(const QString &text, int type) {
        auto *item = new QTreeWidgetItem(QStringList(text));

        switch (type) {
        case IT_ItemWithRegularPadding:
            item->setData(0, Qt::UserRole, QSize(0, 5));
            break;
        case IT_ItemWithBigPadding:
            item->setData(0, Qt::UserRole, QSize(0, 10));
            break;
        }

        return item;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**Note:** This example sets the item's size depending on its index - odd or even. Feel free to change this by implementing the logic you need to differentiate between the items.

### Result

The given example produces the following result:

[image: Tree widget with items of different sizes]

The even and odd items are of a different height.

Comment: I was able to get to the bottom of my issue, the problem was that my `QTreeWidget` was setting `uniformRowHeights` property to true. Taking it off solved the problem.

Comment: Your solution however eliminates the need for `dynamic_cast`, so I upvoted it.

Comment: @ArmaniStyles, my solution is not only simpler, but it is the proper way to have different items' heights by using a delegate. If you let the delegate know about the view which uses it and use its methods, as you do, this is called _tight coupling_ and would cause you troubles at a later stage of your project. So I suggest you to use the approach I've described. You might as well accept the answer, as it gives a valid solution to the question about achieving different heights.

Comment: I do agree with you that your solution is simpler, but I don't agree with the tight coupling part, since it only applies to your sample. The fact of the matter is that I may have 3 different types of `QTreeWidgetItem` and achieve it by sub-classing them. Then I may have logic such that a sub-class of my `QTreeWidget` is creating those items. This means that the `QTreeWidget` will be aware of those types fully. Once it is aware fully there's no harm in calling `dynamic_cast` in the same source file.

Comment: @ArmaniStyles, the use case you describe is indeed interesting and I would be very glad to look for a proper solution for it, if you decide to describe it more specifically in another post.